# Adding an icon to a screensaver

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This might be a simple question, but how to add an icon to a screensaver in XCode ?

I'd added a Assets.xcassets to my project, an AppIcon with all versions possible of the image, but it is still shown with the default icon :(

Any hints of what i am doing wrong or missing ?

Answer (score 2):

### First ensure your General settings are correct:

In order for xcode to know where to pull the App Icon Source you should set this according to the name you assigned to the Icon Set. By default it pulls from AppIcon within your Assets folder. (As seen in the image below)

[image: General Settings]

### Also check all icons for correct dimensions:

If your general settings are correct and you are pulling from the correct icon source. Then the issue may have to do with a one or multiple icon sizes in your Assets folder that are not the correct dimensions. If you are missing icons or have incorrect dimensions the icon will not show up.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ignore the this. The question was about a ScreenSaver and not an Application. Different rules apply in a ScreenSaver.

Answer (score 2):

**Finally got it working.**

Applying AppIcons to a secreensaver is not enough.

You need to add two png images to the project too:

```
thumbnail.png – 90 x 58 pixels
thumbnail@2x.png – 180 x 116 pixels
```

The rest is done automaticly.

Hope this helps, if someone runs into the same problem.